# run jquery function when view on that particular section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a counter that is supposed to count numbers from 0 to 100. However, I have different sections on my page and I only want the counter to start when I am on that particular section of the page so that the user can see the counting. here is my code in html:

```
<div class="one w3-container w3-padding-64" id="counter" style="background:#F1F5FF;"><font style="color:black; overflow:hidden;">
   <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center w3-section">
    <div class="w3-col m3" style="overflow:hidden; min-width:270px; height:230px;border:2px solid black;">    <label for="org">Organizations</label>
    <br><h2>
        <img src="pen.png" style="width:100%; max-width:50px;" alt="microphone v3 icon free sound icons softiconsm" />
        <div id="test" data-from="0" data-to="100">100</div></h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my code in script

```
$.fn.count = function(speed) {
    return this.each(function(_, elem) {
        var from = parseInt($(elem).data('from') || 0, 10),
            to   = parseInt($(elem).data('to') || 45, 10);
        
        $(elem).text(from);
            
        (function run(from, to) {
            $(elem).text(parseInt(from, 10)+1);
            if (from < to-1) setTimeout(function() {run(++from, to)}, speed || 300)
        })(from, to);
    });
}
$('#test').count(80);
```

how can i make this part of the script only run when the user is on div counter on their screen? I don't want the user to miss the counting.

Comment: Use Intersection observer API see MDN docs for more info about it =>       https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: *" user is on div counter on their screen"* - how does he get there? What's the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Where you want your code to be executed just add counter class

As you said you have multiple counters to deal with all of them at once just add counter class in them and use Intersection observer API to deal when the element is in viewport

For eg. In your  #counter div  add class counter and see magic !

```
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".counter");
  const options = {
    threshold: 0.5
  }
  let Observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    function (entries, Observer) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        // Add your code here 
         console.log(" I am visible on viewport")
          Observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    }, options);


  elements.forEach(element => {
    Observer.observe(element);
  })
```

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question.. but where do i add this? do you mean inside my counter div i should write <script> and include this code in? sorry im not sure where to put this code and how.

Comment: It's okay .. you can add this code in script tag and don't forget to add counter class to desired divs   :-)